# Capitalize a word based on a matching word in a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, uppercase

Working through a "Coursera Python" course and I am having a lot of trouble.

The `highlight_word` function changes the given word in a sentence to its upper-case version. For example, `highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice")` returns `"Have a NICE day"`. I want help to rewrite this function in just one line?

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    return(___)

print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
print(highlight_word("Shhh, don't be so loud!", "loud"))
print(highlight_word("Automating with Python is fun", "fun"))
```

I think I can do this in a larger statement but does anyone know how to return this correctly in a single line? I am guessing it will involve a list comprehension.

Comment: You can do it with a simple regular expression replacement.

Comment: You can do it with `split()`, `join()`, and list comprehension, but it will be long and confusing.

Comment: @AndrejKesely That won't respect word boundaries.

Comment: For this simple case (ignoring word boundaries) you could probably do `return sentence.replace(word, word.upper())`

Answer (score 12):

The re.sub works but it was still the incorrect answer and overly complicated - @C. Leconte was correct to use a simple replace.

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
    return(sentence.replace(word,word.upper()))

print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
print(highlight_word("Shhh, don't be so loud!", "loud"))
print(highlight_word("Automating with Python is fun", "fun"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer in one line, in the way that @Barmar hinted at:

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word): return " ".join([x.upper() if x.lower() == word.lower() else x for x in sentence.split()])
```

Basically - split the sentence into words, and use list comprehension to upper() the matching word. Then use join() to bring the sentence back together.

Edit: sentence.split() will split only on whitespace, so it won't capitalize the second example as "loud!" != "loud". In this case, you could use the [regex library](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Regular_Expression) to do a substitution.

Yes it works : 
[image]

Comment: Probably should use `if x.lower() == word`, so it will work for things like `Python`.

Comment: don't do this: `highlight = lambda`

Comment: I cannot get that second example working - I assume they messed up when they made the question because regex hasn't been covered whatsoever yet. Is there a way to check for .isalpha() or something within this statement to look beyond the ! attached?

Could you please show me what the example might be like using regex?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple replace() method on the string to change word to word.upper(), is that forbidden for you?

Comment: I have a question. Does anyone know why my code which is similar to the one above wouldn't work? I thought the if condition has to be at the end of the list comprehension statement.

`return " ".join([x.upper() for x in sentence.split() if x == word else x]) `

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with a [regular expression using re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
  return re.sub(r'\b' + word + r'\b', word.upper(), sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one, it worked for me !

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
  return sentence[0:sentence.index(word)] + word.upper()+ sentence[sentence.index(word)+len(word):]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what the course teaches, the below expression works for me:
`def highlight_word(sentence, word): return(sentence[:sentence.find(word)]+word.upper()+sentence[sentence.find(word)+len(wor d):])`

In this I have used string slicing only

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `re.sub()` functions

```
import re

def highlight_word(sentence, word):
     return [(re.sub(y, y.upper(), x)) for x in sentence for y in word if y in x]


words = ["have a nice day", "Shhh, don't be so loud!","Automating with Python is fun"]
lowers = ['nice','loud','fun']

print(highlight_word(words,lowers))
```

OUTPUT :

```
['have a NICE day', "Shhh, don't be so LOUD!", 'Automating with Python is FUN']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line by using 'replace(string,replaced_string)' as shown:

```
def highlight_word(sentence, word):
return(sentence.replace(sentence[sentence.find(word):sentence.find(word)+len(word)],sentence[sentence.find(word):sentence.find(word)+len(word)].upper()))
```

sentence.replace(sentence[sentence.find(word):sentence.find(word)+len(word)]

and it works for the following inputs:

```
print(highlight_word("Have a nice day", "nice"))
print(highlight_word("Shhh, don't be so loud!", "loud"))
print(highlight_word("Automating with Python is fun", "fun"))
```

You get the following out-put

```
 Have a NICE day
 Shhh, don't be so LOUD!
 Automating with Python is FUN
```